# polymer/resin/material that melts around 40 C

Tags: energy

Does anybody know of a polymer/resin/material that melts around 40 C and has a high heat of melting, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to ChemSE.  For future reference, aim for a more specific question, which in your case could be "what are the conditions you want to use the material, what are chemicals (?) the material would be exposed to". Or, if something *like* $\pu{50 ^\circ{}C}$ already is outside your tolerance / window of application.

Because of the sparse information the question (currently) provides, the answer barely may be more specific than this suggestion:  paraffin waxes.  Among the chemical suppliers, Sigma-Aldrich's online catalogue, for example, lists several of them:

[image]

([source](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/search?term=Paraffin%20wax&interface=Product%20Name&N=0%20&mode=mode%20matchpartialmax&lang=en&region=US&focus=productN=0%20220003048%20219853286%20219853269)).